# Select most popular track for a playlist in a playlists table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a summary table with the stats of all my playlists with the following fields:

`PlaylistName
LatestTrackAddDate
NumberOfTracks
TracksPlayedCount
NumberOfArtists
MostPopularSong`

I can get the all the fields except for the first one with the following query:

```
SELECT p.playlist_name AS 'Playlist Name', 
    MAX(plt.playlisttrack_adddate) 'Latest Track Add Date', 
    COUNT(DISTINCT plt.playlist_id, plt.track_id, plt.user_id, plt.playlisttrack_adddate) As 'Number of Tracks', 
    COUNT(DISTINCT pt.user_id, pt.track_id, playedtrack_datetime) As 'Number of Tracks Played',
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.artist_id) As 'Number of Unique Artists'
FROM playlist p
    JOIN playlisttrack plt ON p.playlist_id = plt.playlist_id
    JOIN tracksource ts ON ts.tracksource_typeid = p.playlist_id
    JOIN playedtrack pt ON pt.tracksource_id = ts.tracksource_id
    JOIN track t ON plt.track_id = t.track_id
        AND pt.track_id = t.track_id
    JOIN trackartist ta ON t.track_id = ta.track_id
    JOIN artist a ON ta.artist_id = a.artist_id
GROUP BY p.playlist_name;
```

I can get the last field in its own query with the following:

```
SELECT playlist_name, track_name, MAX(count_plays)
FROM(
    SELECT p.playlist_name AS playlist_name, 
        t.track_name AS track_name,
        COUNT(pt.playedtrack_datetime)  AS count_plays
    FROM playlist p
        JOIN playlisttrack plt ON p.playlist_id = plt.playlist_id
        JOIN tracksource ts ON ts.tracksource_typeid = p.playlist_id
        JOIN playedtrack pt ON pt.tracksource_id = ts.tracksource_id
        JOIN track t ON plt.track_id = t.track_id
            AND pt.track_id = t.track_id
        JOIN trackartist ta ON t.track_id = ta.track_id
        JOIN artist a ON ta.artist_id = a.artist_id
    GROUP BY p.playlist_name, t.track_name) combined
GROUP BY playlist_name;
```

I'm not quite sure how to combine these two results - any guidance is appreciated! Thank you!

Edit:
If there are multiple tracks that have the max play count, then they would all appear in the table.

Structure of the tables used in these queries (others are omitted):
[Partial snippet of schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwG7t.png)

Comment: How will your output look like if there are more than one track under a playlist has same count of plays which is equal to the maximum count played by any track under that playlist?

Comment: It would help if you could detail the structure of your tables.  You do not need to include fields that are not going to be used as a primary key, foreign key or relevant data.

Comment: Are these stats for a specific user or for all users?

Comment: Can different users add tracks to one playlist?

Comment: @Pons: the output would show all the tracks that have the highest playcount

Comment: @toonice: I will update the post with details on the tables, the query right now is set up to include all users; different users can add tracks to the same playlist

Comment: According to your diagram, different Users can add the same Track to a Playlist.  Is this indeed allowed, and if so are you after the last date a Track was added by any User?  And should the count of Tracks regard them as two tracks or one?

Comment: @toonice the last date a track was added can be done by any user; playlists can have duplicate tracks and will count towards the count; all. My main concern is just the "MostPopularSong" and how to integrate into the existing output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try -

```
SELECT nameOfPlaylist AS "Playlist Name",
       dateTrackLastAdded AS "Latest Track Add Date",
       trackCount AS "Number Of Tracks",
       numberOfTracksPlayed AS "Number Of Tracks Played",
       uniqueArtistCount AS "Number Of Unique Artists",
       playedTrackID AS "Most Popular Song(s)"
FROM
(
    SELECT playlist.playlist_id AS playlist_id,
           playlist.playlist_name AS nameOfPlaylist,
           MAX( playlisttrack.playlisttrack_adddate ) AS dateTrackLastAdded, 
           COUNT( playlisttrack.track_id ) AS trackCount,
           COUNT( DISTINCT playedtrack.track_id ) AS numberOfTracksPlayed,
           COUNT( DISTINCT trackartist.artist_id ) AS uniqueArtistCount,
           playedtrack.track_id AS playedTrackID,
           COUNT( playedtrack.track_id ) AS distributedTrackPlayCount
    FROM playlist
    JOIN playlisttrack ON playlist.playlist_id = playlisttrack.playlist_id
    JOIN tracksource ON tracksource.tracksource_typeid = playlist.playlist_id
    JOIN playedtrack ON playedtrack.tracksource_id = tracksource.tracksource_id
    JOIN track ON playlisttrack.track_id = track.track_id AND playedTrackID = track.track_id
    JOIN trackartist ON track.track_id = trackartist.track_id
    GROUP BY playlist.playlist_name,
             playedTrackID
) withDistributedTrackPlayCount
JOIN
(
    SELECT withConsolidatedTrackCount.playlist_id,
           MAX( consolidatedTrackPlayCount ) AS maxPlayCount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT withDistributedTrackPlayCount.playlist_id AS playlist_id,
               withDistributedTrackPlayCount.playedTrackID AS playedTrackID,
               SUM( distributedTrackPlayCount ) AS consolidatedTrackPlayCount
        FROM withDistributedTrackPlayCount
        GROUP BY withDistributedTrackPlayCount.playlist_id
    ) withConsolidatedTrackCount
) withMaxTrackPlayCount ON withDistributedTrackPlayCount.playlist_id = withMaxTrackPlayCount.playlist_id;
```

Note : I have not been able to test this as I do not have a suitably equivalent database and will have to construct one instead.  If you have scripts to construct and populate the above then please modify your question to include them.

Note : I have assumed that "Number Of Tracks Played" refers to a count of those tracks belonging to a playlist that have been played as part of that playlist at least once.  If it refers to the total number of times that tracks belonging to the playlist have been played as part of the playlist, or something else, then please say so and I will modify my answer.

Note : You have stated that one track can be added to a playlist by more than one user, with each user perhaps adding it more than once.  I have assumed that "Most Popular Song(s)" refers to the total number of plays for a track across all of its listings within a playlist.

I welcome all constructive questions or comments related to this answer.

Comment: Thank you @toonice, your assumptions are all correct. When I run this query I get an error message `Error Code: 1146. Table 'mydb.withdistributedtrackplaycount' doesn't exist
`. I am using MySQL 5.7.17

Comment: I created a view 'withDistributedTrackPlayCount' prior to the SQL statement and removed the subquery `(SELECT ...) withDistributedTrackPlayCount` in the main query. The return statement only gives me one row though, however (the first playlist).

Comment: I have altered the above to remove one theoretical cause of the error.  I have created a sample database based on the diagram and am partway through populating it.  I should be able to do my own testing soon.

Comment: Thank you @toonice, I used views and adapted your version to a working query